# SSRS Textbox Entry Limit Chars

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence

I am looking for a way to limit the entry size of a textbox for an SSRS parameter. The report is being rendered in ReportServer 2008. To be clear, this is NOT a textbox rendered in the report.

The report is accepting a limited number of characters for a text search, and I would like the presentation layer to match the report/SQL logic entry limit. I do not want to get 100 chars passed into a VARCHAR(20) field and produce a silent error.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to limit the length directly. One possible solution would be to have the report return a warning message indicating that the parameter is too long instead of running the query. You can do this by adding a hidden parameter after the parameter in question to be used as a flag that determines the visibility of the objects on the report.

Comment: I was thinking there might be no way to control this area when using Report Server... but I like the work around idea! Thanks.